# App::setLocale is setting the local with null value in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, translation

I am trying to add translation in my website but it didn't translate.
I made controller for localization that is given below

```
class LocalizationController extends Controller {

    public function index($locale) {
        
        App::setLocale($locale);
        
        //store the locale in session so that the middleware can register it
        session()->put('locale', $locale);
        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

Also I made a middleware for localization

Localization.php

```
class Localization {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        App::setLocale(env('APP_LOCALE'));
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

I made folders of languages en,ro,pk etc in my `resources/lang`folder and in that languages folders, I made files in which corresponding translation is given. For Example, for romanian language, the translation is given below

ro.json file

```
{
    "Hi there!": "Salut",
    "How are you doing?": "Ce mai faci?",
    "This is basic example of how you use Laravel Localizations": "Acesta este un exemplu de bază despre cum puteți utiliza localizarea pârghiei"
}
```

and my route is :

```
Route::get('lang/{locale}', 'LocalizationController@index');
```

But I can't find the exact problem that why It is not setting the locale that I choose in dropdown?

Any help would be highly appreciated...Thank you

Comment: Should you not retrieve the locale from the session in your middleware? Currently you are using `env()`, which you should never use outside of configuration files.

Comment: @Remul How can I do it.. I am new..So help me

Comment: Maybe something like `App::setLocale($request->session()->get('locale', config('app.locale')));` in your middleware.

Comment: @Remul how can I access in blade means how my website content is translated?

Comment: Accessing _what_ in blade? Everything you need to know is in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/localization#retrieving-translation-strings).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can implement translations across all pages on Laravel

Add a controller:

```
class LocalizationController extends Controller {
        public function index($locale){
        session()->put('locale', $locale);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

On your web.php:

```
Route::get('/locale/{locale}', [LanguageController::class, 'index']);
```

On your blade view (Language Selector):

```html
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/locale/en">English</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/locale/fr">French</a>
```

That should do the trick!